# Java Regex word boundaries \\bbackup\\b

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match 2 patterns that have the string Copy-Of in them. I am using word boundaries \b...\b for my match but i am having a problem.

```
string = "This is a backup-Copy-Of your CD can you make a Copy-Of it?"
```

Now, I want to match backup-Copy-Of and Copy-Of

```
if (Pattern.compile("\\bCopy-Of\\b").matcher(Parameter).find()) {
```

This will match both Copy-Of from (backup-Copy-Of) and Copy-Of itself.

The program still runs up to this point but when I add the line below it  errors.

```
if (Pattern.compile("\\bbackup-Copy-Of\\b").matcher(Parameter).find()) {
```

And if I removed the first pattern match ("\bCopy-Of\b") and leave only the 2nd pattern ("\bbackup-Copy-Of\b"), it runs without any issues.

```
So What is the correct way to match for backup-Copy-Of and Copy-Of.
```

The results should be:

```
1 match for  backup-Copy-Of
1 match for Copy-Of
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `i` modifier because `o` in the `Of` is in lowercase but in the input it's in uppercase and also you must need to make `up` as optional since the regex contains `backup` but in the input it's `back`.

```
if (Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bback(?:up)?-Copy-of\\b").matcher(Parameter).find()) {
```

or

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)back(?:up)?-Copy-Of(?!\\S)").matcher(Parameter);
if(m.find()) {
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wG7aS9/1)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I updated the question. for some reason \\bb is breaking the program and if I changed it to \\b\b it will run but of course it won't match anything.

Comment: did you check the `up` in `backup` ? `Pattern.compile("\\bback(?:up)?-Copy-Of\\b").matcher(Parameter);` demo https://regex101.com/r/wG7aS9/2

Comment: it's not the problem with word boundaries.. you may try removing the `up` like `Pattern.compile("\\bback-Copy-Of\\b").matcher(Parameter);`

Comment: Did you check my update? For this case, replace `\\b` with lookarounds. **PLease check my edit.**